# What is the purpose of the key used with CIFilter?

Tags: swift, core-image, cifilter

```
let filter: CIFilter!
filter = CIFilter(name: "Sepo")
filter.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
```

What is the key doing? Is it naming the image that I am putting in or what? It has such a confusing name it makes no sense.

Comment: I've never heard of a filter called 'Sepo.'

Comment: @ElTomato Masculine form of Sepia

Answer (score 1):

Filters are configured the same way you populate a dictionary — with keys and values. Each filter has parameters you can hand to it; to tell it what parameter you are handing it, you provide a key along with the parameter's value. Your `image` is the incoming image, so you must tell the filter that. So your code says, "Please accept this image and use it as your input image." If you don't like the mysterious name, use `"inputImage"` as the key instead.

Comment: but the keys already exist, im just picking specific keys.. wut.. explain pls

Comment: Each filter tells you what keys it accepts. But most filters operate on an image, so most filters have a input image key of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs ([source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/kciinputimagekey?language=objc)):

> A key for the CIImage object to use as an input image. For filters that also use a background image, this key refers to the foreground image.